# Where can I subscribe a newsletter that informs me about the newest Drupal 7 releases?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I want to keep an web page (Drupal 7) updated and install the security fixes as soon as possible. The releases are listed here:

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases?api_version%5B%5D=103

I do not want to look every day into this list. Is there any newsletter, that informs me only about these releases (no advertisement, new modules, etc...)?

Answer (score 2):

Drupal will automatically check for available updates and inform you via email if there are any. It's default behavior and should work unless somebody turned it off.

It's at: Reports -> Available updates -> Settings

Path is:
/admin/reports/updates/settings